# Display a popup window before the mainwindow runs

Tags: qt, popup

How can I make a popup window that appears before the mainwindow begins? I want the popup to have several `QLineEdit` widgets to receive input that I will need for the mainwindow. I searched for solutions, but I could not understand most of the examples I found. Can some one help me?

Comment: What do you have so far? Post a link to the examples and we'll try to walk you through.

Comment: Or just an idea: you could try to subclass `QSplashScreen`...

Comment: using `QSplashScreen` where do we define stuff? main.cpp or mainwindow.cpp

Comment: Unless you subclass it, no, I don't think `QSplashScreen` has edit boxes. As an alternative, you may want to consider a basic `QWidget`, like a `QDialog` or whatever, that you'd display first, your mainwindow being invisible. Then, when this widget is closed, you make your mainwindow visible again.

Comment: how can i create that widget. I know this is a basic question but i'm confused right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15915/discussion-between-pierre-gm-and-samuelnlp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a subclass of QDialog, execute it modally before running your normal startup logic.

Thats how I did it for an app that required a login, worked just fine.  This would be the general idea in Python (it takes me less time to think about it in PyQt):

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from mymodule import MyDialog, MyWindow

def main(argv):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)

    # make a dialog that runs in its own event loop
    dlg = MyDialog()
    if ( not dlg.exec_() ):  # in C++, this would be dlg->exec()
        sys.exit(0)

    var1, var2, var3 = dlg.values()        

    window = MyWindow()
    window.setPropertyOne(var1)
    window.setPropertyTwo(var2)
    window.setPropertyThree(var3)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: how do i create the .ui file linking to this?

Comment: can you see this and see if you can help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180617/hide-qdialog-and-show-mainwindow

Comment: sure, i just answered over there too